# Подключение сторонних библиотек в Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как подключить в Kohana стороннюю библиотеку, а именно Simple Html Dom. Нашел в интернете, что нужно помещать в application/vendor, а потом обращаться к ней с помощью

```
require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'vendor/simple_html_dom.php');
```

Но так выводится ошибка

> Fatal error:
> Controller_Index::action_index()
> [function.require]: Failed opening
> required ''
> (include_path='.;W:\modules\php\PHP-5.3.27;W:\modules\php\PHP-5.3.27\PEAR\pear')
> in
> W:\domains\parser.loc\www\application\classes\Controller\index.php
> on line 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
include_once Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel', 'php');
```

В Вашем случае:

```
include_once Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'simple_html_dom','php);
```